# Plesk IP Address defaults to new site

Tags: ip-address, plesk

I manage a Plesk (12) server with a single dedicated IP address. rDNS is set to a generic hostname as multiple unrelated websites are hosted on the same server.

In `Tools & Settings` > `IP Addresses` I've set the default site to "None" so that no particular website loads by default when the IP is visited directly. However, when I add a new domain, that automatically becomes the default website for the IP and I have to go back into `Tools & Settings` > `IP Addresses` to change it back to "None" every time.

[image: Plesk default IP Address]

Is there a way to set the default website on the IP to none and have that setting stick?

Comment: I have set the IP address as shared and the default site is none, and stays that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set your IP address to be distributed as a shared IP address then the default site will stay as none even when you add new domains.

If it's a shared IP then the server doesn't know what site to show when clicking the IP address, unless you specify it. I seem to recall having to specify the site in times past for dedicated IP addresses though, so if they are defaulting to a whatever domain then that's useful as dedicated IP's normally have just one domain on.